# Jackson serialization and deserialization of a 3rd party class without writing a custom serializer and or deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson

This question will probably sound like a duplicate but I can't piece together a complete solution to my problem.

I've tried using custom ser/deser classes but that gets tedious really fast (and defeats the automation that Jackson is meant to provide) and I've tried mixin's but maybe I'm missing something.

I'd even be okay with trying a different json library so long as it can serialize and deserialize 3rd party classes like I've shown without a lot of effort.

I've tried this. Which results in a StackOverflowError.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.addMixIn(Word.class, WordMixin.class);
String ser = om.writeValueAsString(t);
Word r = om.readValue(ser, Word.class);
```

I've tried this. Which results an exception being thrown *InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `net.sourceforge.tess4j.Word` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)*

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.setVisibility(om.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
    .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
    .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY));
String ser = om.writeValueAsString(t);
Word r = om.readValue(ser, Word.class);
```

My mixin class

```
public static class WordMixin {
        @JsonCreator
        public WordMixin(@JsonProperty String text, @JsonProperty float confidence, @JsonProperty Rectangle rect){}
    }
```

Third party class.

```
public class Word {

    private final String text;
    private final float confidence;
    private final Rectangle rect;

    public Word(String text, float confidence, Rectangle boundingBox) {
        this.text = text;
        this.confidence = confidence;
        this.rect = boundingBox;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public float getConfidence() {
        return confidence;
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundingBox() {
        return rect;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s [Confidence: %f Bounding box: %d %d %d %d]", text, confidence, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my mixin class was defined inside of another class which requires the **static abstract** decorator on the mixin class.

Here is my full answer.

Third party class **Word.java**

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Word {

    private final String text;
    private final float confidence;
    private final Rectangle rect;

    public Word(String text, float confidence, Rectangle boundingBox) {
        this.text = text;
        this.confidence = confidence;
        this.rect = boundingBox;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public float getConfidence() {
        return confidence;
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundingBox() {
        return rect;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s [Confidence: %f Bounding box: %d %d %d %d]", text, confidence, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
    }
}
```

**JacksonHelper.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class JacksonHelper {

    // Don't call any functions when serializing or deserializing.
    // Only look at the public class variables.
    @JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            creatorVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY
    )
    public static abstract class RectangleMixin {}

    // Don't call any functions when serializing or deserializing.
    // Only look at the class variables of any visibility (including private)
    @JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            creatorVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
            fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY
    )
    public static abstract class WordMixin {
        @JsonCreator
        public WordMixin(@JsonProperty("text") String text, @JsonProperty("confidence") float confidence,
                         @JsonProperty("boundingBox") Rectangle boundingBox) {}
    }

}
```

**WordTest.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WordTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.addMixIn(Rectangle.class, JacksonHelper.RectangleMixin.class);
        om.addMixIn(Word.class, JacksonHelper.WordMixin.class);

        Word word = new Word("t1", 12, new Rectangle(1, 3));
        String ser = om.writeValueAsString(word);
        Word r = om.readValue(ser, Word.class);
        System.out.println(ser);
        // {"text":"t1","confidence":12.0,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1,"height":3}}
    }
}
```

Using the @JsonAutoDetect annotation tells Jackson that all of the functions are superfluous. This reduces a lot of bloat in the serialization. The WordMixin constructor tells Jackson how to call the Word constructor, but is never called itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should register dedicated `Mixin` for `java.awt.Rectangle` and add `@JsonIgnore` for `bounds2D` to stop recursion that cause `StackOverflow`.

Have a look at the code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WordTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.addMixIn(Rectangle.class, RectangleMixin.class);
        om.addMixIn(Word.class, WordMixin.class);

        Word word = new Word("t1", 12, new Rectangle(1, 3));
        String ser = om.writeValueAsString(word);
        Word r = om.readValue(ser, Word.class);
    }
}
```

**RectangleMixin.java**:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public abstract class RectangleMixin {

    @JsonProperty("width")
    public abstract double getWidth();

    @JsonProperty("height")
    public abstract double getHeight();

    @JsonIgnore
    public abstract Rectangle2D getBounds2D();
}
```

**WordMixin.java** :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.awt.*;

public abstract class WordMixin {
    @JsonCreator
    public WordMixin(@JsonProperty("text") String text, @JsonProperty("confidence") float confidence,
                     @JsonProperty("boundingBox") Rectangle boundingBox) {}
}
```

Comment: Your solution solves the StackOverflowError and I can serialize the Word class now, but I still can't deserialize the Word class because I don't understand how to write a "Creator", as Jackson calls it, without the class having a default constructor.

Comment: Did you try WordMixin.java from the answer as standalone class?

Comment: I was able to get your code to work by making a separate project for this issue. The first thing I tried was making the mixin classes standalone and that worked for me. If I declare WordMixin as a subclass with the **static** and **abstract** keywords i.e. `public static abstract class WordMixin` inside of a public class, then it works.